# Uninstalling Genymotion (v2.2.2) on Ubuntu (v14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, genymotion

I installed Genimotion (v2.2.2), but I seem to have problems with it, as I couldn't play the devices I downloaded for it (tried several devices).

I tried reinstalling VirtualBox (v4.3.10) but it didn't help either...

Now I want to try reinstalling the Genimotion itself, but I cant find an uninstallation shell or any way to uninstall it (I also tried running the command:

> sudo apt-get --purge remove genymotion

in the installation folder, but it didn't detect and removed the files).

I saw many people who suggested reinstalling it but never they didn't mention how, so I hope it's not a really stupid question...

Thank you

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `.bin` file you have downloaded to install it can also be run with `--uninstall` argument to uninstall genymotion. In your case the command will be something like:

```
./genymotion-2.2.2_x64.bin --uninstall
```

You can often discover command usage with the argument `--help`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer,
I'm new to the linux system and I couldn't find how the command should look like. I tried `sudo apt-get --uninstall genymotion-2.2.2_x64.bin` , but I guess  it's just not right to to that...

Comment: `apt-get uninstall` can be used only on applications that have been installed using `apt-get install`, that one instead was installed using a bin file, so you usually need the bin file again in order to uninstall it, because it contains all the logic.

Comment: That's great to know, It might help me find my way in the Linux better. Thanks again

Comment: When I execute this command, it doesnt works it shows permission denied.

Comment: "You can often discover command usage with the argument --help." simple but  clever tip :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

I did need to use -d at the end of the uninstall to send it to the path.

./genymotion-2.12.2-linux_x64.bin --uninstall -d /home/genymotion

Answer (score 1):

the command `./genymotion-2.2.2_x64.bin --uninstall` (x86 in my pc), worked perfectly, did you erase any of the genymotion files from the folder? if you did, you're gonna have to reinstall it from the beginning, and run this command again(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

if you deleted your `./genymotion-x.x.x_x64.bin --uninstall` file.
then just use following command:

```bash
sudo rm -rf {enter_path}/genymotion
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/genymobile-genymotion.desktop
```

[Note: genymotion 3.2.1 or later wants location if `-d` is mentioned otherwise it's gonna installed on the current directory]